# How to create a transition like this one?

Tags: android, animation, transition

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s400/activity_transitions%2B%281%29.gif

This is a material animation I want to implement, but I can't achieve a similar effect. First of all, the shared element transition moves the image into the second activity. This is quite simple, but then the root layout of the activity starts expanding and during the animation the user can see the first activity until the second activity's view doesn't hide it totally.

Comment: Hi, did you implemented it?

Comment: I think it contains 3 sequential animations: transition of cover image, square reveal layout, and the last one is scale playback button. 
I don't know what type of interpolator in the transition effect :-?

Comment: No, unfortunately I couldn't. I tried to implement the appearing of the second activity, but the semi-transparent view was terrible. So there were some issues I had to cope with, but I didn't have time for that.